# Split a DataFrame into 2 in one scan

Tags: python, pandas

Say there is following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [1,4,9,16]})
```

If I have to split it into 2 dataframes, we can do in following way

```
df1 = df[df['B'] < 5]
df2 = df[df['B'] >= 5]
```

But here df would be scanned twice.
Is there anyway to split DataFrame into 2 in single efficient line; with one scan?

Edit:
Even @jezrael suggestion performs similarly:

```
m = df['B'] < 5
#better performance with comparing numpy array
#m = df['B'].values < 5
df1 = df[m]
df2 = df[~m]
```

Comment: does `df1` and `df2` need to be DataFrames? If they are arrays, it may be possible to speed this up.

Comment: Yes, DataFrames. But for arrays also, I didn't find any numpy function to do it. Anyway we can create our own loop and do it in one scan.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, need invert condition by `~`:

```
m = df['B'] < 5
#better performance with comparing numpy array
#m = df['B'].values < 5
df1 = df[m]
df2 = df[~m]
```

**Performance** - all methods are similar with `1M` rows:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(10, size=N),
                   'B': np.random.randint(10, size=N)})
print (df)

In [53]: %%timeit
    ...: df1 = df[df['B'] < 5]
    ...: df2 = df[df['B'] >= 5]
    ...: 
38.5 ms ± 472 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [54]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df['B'] < 5
    ...: df1 = df[m]
    ...: df2 = df[~m]
    ...: 
37.3 ms ± 298 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [55]: %%timeit
    ...: df1 = df[df['B'].values < 5]
    ...: df2 = df[df['B'].values >= 5]
    ...: 
37.8 ms ± 374 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [56]: %%timeit
    ...: m = df['B'].values < 5
    ...: df1 = df[m]
    ...: df2 = df[~m]
    ...: 
36.8 ms ± 257 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Solution from another answer:

```
In [70]: %%timeit
    ...: sampled_dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['B']<5)]
    ...: df1 = sampled_dfs[0]
    ...: df2 = sampled_dfs[1]
    ...: 
76.9 ms ± 1.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Yes, I also tried with a million rows. The timings were similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` as written below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4], 'B': [1,4,9,16]})
sampled_dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['B']<5)]
print(sampled_dfs[0])
print(sampled_df[1])
```

Output:

```
  A B
2 3 9
3 4 16

  A B
0 1 1
1 2 4
```

Comment: It is slowier, added timings to my answer.

Comment: This should be the recommended solution. Almost certainly, `list` creation is *not* the bottleneck. It promotes good practice of *not* creating additional variables. In addition, it alleviates the main problem of calculating the mask twice.

Comment: Note you can also use `dict(tuple(df.groupby(df['B'] < 5))` for a dictionary

Comment: @jezrael, Sure, "overcomplication" *might* be a good argument. Arguing about timings is *not*.

Comment: @jpp - Sure, I add performance only because OP need it `Is there anyway to split DataFrame into 2 in single efficient line; with one scan?`

Comment: This takes more than 2 times the other two methods                                  `%%timeit
df1 = df[df['B'] < 5]
df2 = df[df['B'] >= 5]
95 ms ± 723 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

2) `%%timeit
m = df['B'] < 5
#better performance with comparing numpy array
#m = df['B'].values < 5
df1 = df[m]
df2 = df[~m]
92.9 ms ± 1.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

3) `%%timeit
sampled_dfs = [x for _, x in df.groupby(df['B']<5)]
213 ms ± 3.48 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`